# GET request params dissapear after sending form to the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form on root page that is handled by flights#index and is located at root. I want that form to submit a GET request to the same page, find appropriate flights and display them. Unfortunately these parameters don't persist.

For this issue I created new rails project and tried to recreate the problem:

```sh
rails new get-req-test
rails g controller Flights
```

And only modified these files below:

**config/routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "flights#index"
end
```

**app/controllers/flights_controller.rb**

```
class FlightsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**app/views/flights/index.html.erb**

```rb
<%= form_with(method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :text1 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :text2 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :text3 %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

<% params.each do |k,v| %>
    <p><%= "#{k}: #{v}" %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I use debugger embedded in the end of *index.html.erb* file, I get all parameters I submitted but those params don't show in website, only controller: flights, action: index.

By submitting `abc` `def` `ghi` in corresponding text boxes I receive this output in server:

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&text1=abc&text2=def&text3=ghi&commit=Save%20changes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-21 21:01:55 +0300
Processing by FlightsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "text1"=>"abc", "text2"=>"def", "text3"=>"ghi", "commit"=>"Save changes"}
  Rendering flights/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered flights/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 13.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And the page itself hasn't changed.

Comment: Do you want this request to show the params you received in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `remote: true` that the `form_with` method adds by default.

Try instead using `<%= form_with method: "get", local: true do %>`

**Reference:** https://medium.com/@tinchorb/form-with-building-html-forms-in-rails-5-1-f30bd60ef52d